# How to pass file in Wep API in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: model-view-controller, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I want to pass file in web api

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
        {
            string d = file.FileName;

            //string contents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = objAPI.CallAPIGet("/BusinessProfile/saveFolder", d))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseString))
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Web Api:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("saveFolder")]
        public IActionResult WriteFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            string fileName;
            try
            {
                var extension = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
                //fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + extension; //Create a new Name 

                fileName = file.FileName;
                var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\BProfileFile", fileName);

                using (var bits = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                     file.CopyToAsync(bits);
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return Ok(fileName);
        }
```

from UI to web api method is not heat. the error is 
Unsupported Media Type.
How to solve this error.

Comment: Where did you get this error, call `Upload` from ui or call `WriteFile` from web api?

Comment: In Upload method,on response getting the error.

Comment: and the error is unsupported mediatype.

Comment: It is not heating api

Comment: If your issue is in `Upload`, share us the code for `CallAPIGet`.

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage CallAPIGet(string ApiMethod, string contents1)
        {
}

Comment: string apiUrl = _settings.Value.ApiUrl;

            HttpResponseMessage response1;
            string URL = apiUrl + ApiMethod;

Comment: using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "Y2JlOmNiZQ==");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                response1 = client.PostAsync(URL, new StringContent(contents1, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;               
            }

Comment: return response1;

Comment: This is my CallAPIGet method.\